# Youtube API display random video & thumbnail

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, thumbnails

I have the videos loading and playing, but i can't get the thumbnail to display at the side of the video.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
function rotateYT() {
    var videos = ['usewkEuDVjU',
                  'IL9iemWe_g8',
        'gGMi60M5O98',
        'SN3CgQvqzAo',
        'W1YFnHjjG8s',
        'l9qMYZvG7EE',
        'j_ljOjr54gc',
        'MhczSQtIgNM',
        'j_ljOjr54gc',
        'T-GPePrh7rw',
        'LTNQFYARFOk',
        'ehciyVuCyvs',
        'g4xSmh0LF6Y',
        'shM7cV-fR9o',];

    var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    return videos[index];
}
</script>

<script>

// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);





    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var videoID = rotateYT();
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          border: '0',
          version: '3',
          showinfo: '0',
          rel: '0',
          controls: '0',
          loop: '0',
          allowfullscreen: '0',
          videoId: videoID,



          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.

  // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {

    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            window.location="mainvids1computers.html" // redirect


        }
    }
</script>



<div id="player" style="position:fixed; top:0%; left:0%; width:100px; height:100px;">


<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+videos[index]+'1.jpg/" style="top:100px; left:100px; width:120px; height:180px;">


</div>
```

My problem is appending the +videos[index]+ with the img tag. All i get at present is the default img, So its obviously not getting the video id and appending correctly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

to match between video and thumbnail add `videoID` outside function, for your player thumbnail it should not called like `<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+videos[index]+'1.jpg/" style=...` this is not valid javascript. last `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` should be on the `window` object.

```js
function rotateYT() {
  var videos = ['usewkEuDVjU',
    'IL9iemWe_g8',
    'gGMi60M5O98',
    'SN3CgQvqzAo',
    'W1YFnHjjG8s',
    'l9qMYZvG7EE',
    'j_ljOjr54gc',
    'MhczSQtIgNM',
    'j_ljOjr54gc',
    'T-GPePrh7rw',
    'LTNQFYARFOk',
    'ehciyVuCyvs',
    'g4xSmh0LF6Y',
    'shM7cV-fR9o',
  ];

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
  return videos[index];
}
// get random video ID
var videoID = rotateYT();

document.getElementById('player-thumb').src = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ videoID +'/1.jpg';

// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// create youtube player
var player;

window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    border: '0',
    version: '3',
    showinfo: '0',
    rel: '0',
    controls: '1',
    loop: '0',
    allowfullscreen: '0',
    videoId: videoID,

    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {

}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if(event.data === 0) {
    window.location = "mainvids1computers.html" // redirect
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="player" style="position:fixed; top:0%; left:0%; width:240px; height:180px;" allowfullscreen>

<img id="player-thumb" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/default.jpg" style="top:100px; left:100px; width:240px; height:180px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Ok Thank you sir, I appreciate the Info and work around v.much , i find it best to have the solution and then figure out how it works, rather than twiddling my thumbs all day with no clue... So i am very great full for your help. i have slightly changed the code since to suit my own code... i posted it for anybody whom may have a similar issue. Thank you

Comment: @russbaker2016 if this answer solved your problem. please consider accept it. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on ewwink's answer for Anybody whome is climbing the same ladder as myself...

Here you can now see the Thumbnail 1st without loading the video. then on mouse event the video loads...

Heres the code...

```
<div id="player" style="position:fixed; top:0%; left:0%; width:100px; height:100px;" allowfullscreen>
</div>

<div id="ewwinkthumbnailed-it">
<img id="player-thumb" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/default.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:120px; width:100px; height:100px;" onmouseover="change();">
</div>


<script>
function rotateYT() {
  var videos = ['usewkEuDVjU',
    'IL9iemWe_g8',
    'gGMi60M5O98',
    'SN3CgQvqzAo',
    'W1YFnHjjG8s',
    'l9qMYZvG7EE',
    'j_ljOjr54gc',
    'MhczSQtIgNM',
    'j_ljOjr54gc',
    'T-GPePrh7rw',
    'LTNQFYARFOk',
    'ehciyVuCyvs',
    'g4xSmh0LF6Y',
    'shM7cV-fR9o',
  ];

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
  return videos[index];
}
// get random video ID
var videoID = rotateYT();

document.getElementById('player-thumb').src = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ videoID +'/1.jpg';

// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.



function change() {
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// create youtube player
var player;

window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '100px',
    width: '100px',
    border: '0',
    version: '3',
    showinfo: '0',
    rel: '0',
    controls: '1',
    loop: '0',
    allowfullscreen: '0',
    videoId: videoID,

    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {

}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if(event.data === 0) {
    window.location = "mainvids1computers.html" // redirect
  }
}
};

</script>
```